# How to specify repc's output path in qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake, qtremoteobjects

in qmake I have

```
REPC_SOURCE = rpc/SomeRPC.rep
```

and it generates `rep_SomeRPC_source.h` in the root of the project. I would like to store it somewhere else to keep root as clean as possible.
Documentation says `repc creates the rep_SimpleSwitch_source.h header in the build directory that you specify`. But how to specify `build directory`?
The only option I see is to change `OUT_PWD`, but documentation says `Do not attempt to overwrite the value of this variable.`

Comment: That file is created in the build directory and not in the project directory so I think it is a configuration problem, how do you compile your project? If you use QtCreator then it will be created in the build-xxx folder, if you use qmake in the console then they are created next to the executable

Comment: @eyllanesc, I run qmake && make from root of the project and 'DESTDIR = build/bin'

Comment: Therein lies the problem: the build directory is where you run qmake. I recommend doing the following: `mkdir build` `cd build` `qmake ../` `make`

Comment: @eyllanesc I see. Thanks for a note! Think that was basic misunderstanding of qmake tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build directory is the folder where you run qmake (in your case it seems to be the project folder) causing the unwanted effect of obtaining a folder with the source code, intermediate files and binaries.

Instead use a different folder where you run qmake:

```
mkdir build
cd build
qmake /path/of/project-directory
make
```